# R: get a list of short file names (filenames) for all files in a directory

Tags: r, windows, directory, filenames, short-filenames

#### Problem

`list.files(Path)` returns a vector of names of files in the directory `Path`. This is great, but I need a vector of short file names (SFN). For instance, the SFN for WageDataFile.csv is WAGEDA~1.csv (if there is no other file in the directory with the stem "WageDa"). The SFN is also called the 8.3 filename.

#### Desired solution

Specifically, I am hoping for a function that will pull the SFN from the OS rather than reconstruct it from the output of `list.files()` (but methods to reconstruct the SFN from the output of `list.files()` are welcome, too).

#### Code for reproducible case

This will create a set of files at "E:/FileNameTest" with variable name lengths:

```
setwd("E:/FileNameTest")
library(stringi)
nFiles = 12
minNameLength = 2
maxNameLength = 12
set.seed(1)
FileNames = 
    stri_rand_strings(nFiles, 
                length=sample(minNameLength:maxNameLength,nFiles,replace=T), 
                '[A-Za-z0-9]')
file.create(FileNames)
```

Here is the content of `FileNames`:

```
 [1] "lUizNmvDe7"   "GN0Nr"        "LTbUBpfn"     "6i"           "Poe"          "mYWm1Tjg"    
 [7] "TrRF46JWfPuI" "SKe"          "FTl5sLqLKTtr" "OmxQ"         "iO"           "KkCi7F"
```

Here is the list of SFN that I need from those file names (edit: the names that were shortened should be in all caps):

```
[1] "6i"       "FTL5SL~1" "GN0Nr"    "iO"       "KkCi7F"   "LTbUBpfn" "LUIZNM~1" "mYWm1Tjg" "OmxQ"    
[10] "Poe"      "SKe"      "TRRF46~1"
```

Comment: This seems to be windows specific stuff. R tries to be OS-unaware. You can get short names from the Windows `dir` shell command: `shell("dir /x")`. But why exactly do you need the short names?

Comment: I need to read in the text of thousands of files with names that are too long for Windows file paths. readLines() does not work with the long paths. Solutions that have been proposed to this problem include creating a virtual drive that points to the directory, but I actually have thousands of directories to go through, and creating virtual drives for all of them seems like a much worse solution than just using the SFN for each file. Another solution might be to rename the files with another platform, but the names contain data I need.

Comment: Short names can be turned off, you should just handle spaces instead. And spaces are technically possible in 8.3 names.

Comment: @Anders do you mean that it is possible to increase the character limit on Windows file names (with the "Enable NTFS long paths" policy)? I am not sure what issue with spaces you are talking about.

Comment: No, I mean that it is possible to turn off 8.3 names and when you do that you only get the long names, no "...~1" names exist. And if you don't have problem with spaces, why do you care about short names in the first place?

Comment: Microsoft's filesystems support paths with up to 32,767 characters (or a bit less, depending on the initial device path length). Your problem is due to DOS path translation, which has a legacy limit of 260 characters. Long-path support in Windows 10 removes this limit in most cases, but it has to be enabled at the system level and also in the application manifest, which I suppose is r.exe in this case. Otherwise the way to access long paths is to bypass DOS path translation by using a "\\?\" prefixed path, which has to be Unicode, fully-qualified, and only use backslash as the path separator.

Comment: Other ways, which you appear to be aware of already, are to mount a directory as a drive-letter junction via subst.exe (i.e WINAPI `DefineDosDeviceW`), which can target a path of about 4K characters. Or use a symbolic link or junction reparse point, which can also target a path of about 4K characters (limited by the max reparse buffer size of 16 KiB, split between display and substitute paths). Neither approach is practical if you need concurrent access to thousands of unique long paths.

Comment: Note that changing the working directory is not a supported workaround. The working directory can only be set to a long path if it's enabled in Windows 10 for the system and application. Someone clueless changed the docs for `SetCurrentDirectoryW` to claim that it supports long "\\?\" paths. It's doubly bad advice because not only is the underlying buffer limited to 260 characters prior to Windows 10, but the API has also never supported setting the working directory to  a device path (i.e. "\\?\" and "\\.\" prefixes). The NT runtime library is quite buggy in this case; clearly not tested.

Comment: Really helpful comments, @eryksun. It is not an answer to this question, but I ended up being able to solve my problem without getting the SFN by reading in the files with `shell(paste0("type //?/", getwd(),"/",FileName), translate=T, intern=T)` instead of `readLines()`. Unfortunately, this is much slower.

Comment: You shouldn't have to use the shell. Unicode device paths using backslash as the path separator should be supported (e.g. "\\\\?\\C:\\long\\path\\to\\file", given backslash has to be escaped in a string literal). Unfortunately I don't know anything about R.

Comment: You are right (and you saved me many hours of computer time)!

Comment: shortPathName("C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.4/lib/x64") returns "C:\\PROGRA~1\\NVIDIA~2\\CUDA\\v11.4\\lib\\x64" on my end

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution (based on a comment from MrFlick) that may rely on invalid assumptions about the output of `dir`. Specifically, I assume that the header and footer of the output always take up 5 and 2 lines, respectively, and that the width of fields in the `dir /x/a:-d` output is always constant.

```
library(stringr)
FileList = shell("dir /x/a:-d", intern=T)
FileList = FileList[6:(length(FileList)-2)]
SFN = str_replace(str_sub(FileList, 39, 46), "        ", "")
Name = str_sub(FileList, 52, -1)
NameList = ifelse(str_length(SFN)>0, SFN, Name)
```